# Getting user ID when calling an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table for doing CRUD operations on books, and also users can check in books (the checking out is done my a different controller)

At the moment the check in works for the book table, but I can't update user data - the integer of how many books they have loaned out

Here is part of my table:

```
    <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= book.title %></td>
        <td><%= book.author %></td>
        <td class ="onloan"><%= book.onloan %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'show', book %> </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_book_path(book) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <td><%=  link_to 'Check in', check_in_path(book)%></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

What I want to add is something like

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.books_on_loan - 1
```

Here is the check in def of my controller:

```
def check_in
 Book.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:onloan, 0)
 redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: should be `update_attribute(onloan: 0)`, and you should consider the record maybe cannot found.

Comment: what are your params ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the `books_on_loan` column/attribute of the `@user` deducting `1` each time you execute the `check_in` action, you will need to change your method to do something like this:

```
def check_in
  @book = Book.find params[:id]

  if @book.update_attribute :onloan, 0
    @user = User.find params[:user_id] # Or change to get `@user.id` attribute
    @user.books_on_loan = @user.books_on_loan - 1 # Current value - 1
    @user.save
  end

  redirect_to root_path
end
```

**EDIT:**

You will need to know the User ID by some way, as I commented on code you will need to change `params[:user_id]` by the variable containing the user ID.

If you don't have the ID on HTTP params you will need to find it by inside. In your example you are finding User by `params[:id]`, but this is actually the param of the Book ID in this action and it can't be the same as User.

Your example is not enough to determine how to achieve the User ID, but I will suggest you to store it on the Book record. If the Book is unique and only one User can take it, you can add a column `user_id` to the Books, for example, and then you can get the User ID form the Book. Example:

```
def check_in
  @book = Book.find params[:id]

  if @book.update_attribute :onloan, 0
    @user = User.find @book.user_id
    @user.books_on_loan = @user.books_on_loan - 1 # Current value - 1
    @user.save
  end

  redirect_to root_path
end
```

This way you can also put a `belongs_to :user` on the Book model and get the user by `@book.user` on your controller.

And better: you can get "books on loan" of an User by simple doing a `@user.books.count` if you have a `has_many :books` on your User model. Doing it you can remove the `books_on_loan` attribute of you Book with the update approach.

Anyway, you will need to set the `user_id` of the Book probably on the `check_out` action (Im assuming you have one) of your controller.

If you do it your `check_in` action will be like this:

```
def check_in
  @book = Book.find params[:id]

  @book.onloan = 0
  @book.user_id = nil # There is no User with the Book
  @book.save

  redirect_to root_path
end
```

If this still complicated you can take a look in the **Active Record Associations** guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: When I do this I get an error - 'Couldn't find User with 'id'='. The problem is I can't get the User params.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_in
  @book = Book.find params[:id]

  if @book.update_attribute :onloan, 0
    @user = User.find params[:user_id] # Or change to get `@user.id` attribute
    @user.books_on_loan = @user.books_on_loan - 1 # Current value - 1
    @user.save
  end

  redirect_to root_path
end
```

This is ok, but if you want to grab the user id, you need to specify your params value. Either in path or nested routes is fine.

According to your case, I don't think you have nested routes.

So hidden attribute or simply `check_in_path(book, user_id: your_desired_user_id)` is fine